# Returned with object from db call

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I execute the following code;

```
 var array = await Promise.all([
    database.query("SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM transactions WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;"), 
    database.query("SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM transactions WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;"), 
    database.query("SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM transactions"), 
  ]);
```

I expect an array like so [1,2,3];

Instead what I get is;

```
[ [ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(amount)': 6 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(amount)': 7 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(amount)': 7 } ] ]
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1330, it is because it is a low level library.

You can still access the array with `[0]['COUNT(amount)']` and so on. If you just want the numbers you may have too add more logic.

Comment: Shame. It really annoys me.

Comment: @Borda it shouldn't, because it takes 2 seconds to write a re-usable function that wraps `query` and returns a single value. If your library of choice _would_ supply this feature it would also just be this exact same function. This is a learning opportunity.